# Send parameters from c# to CEF

Tags: c#, parameters, chromium-embedded

I have a windows applicaion that has CEF to display some web pages from another solution. I was wondering if I can send parameters from c# to CEF which I can use in my web pages...Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to execute external JS code in the context of your page. For example, you can define a global JS function inside a web page:

```
function acceptExternalParameters(a, b, c) {
    console.log(a, b, c);
}
```

and then execute a script from C# code:

```
browser.GetMainFrame().ExecuteJavaScriptAsync("acceptExternalParameters(1, 2, 3)");
```